# Verifying a set is a subgroup - Clarification on second induction principle

Tags: group-theory, induction

I'm reading a book that states the following theorem:

> Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a nonempty subset of G. If $ab^{-1}$ is in $H$
>   whenever $a$ and $b$ are in $H$, then $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

They then list a 4 step verification process:

> 1. Identify the property $P$ that distinguishes the elements of $H$; that is, identify a defining condition.
> 2. Prove that the identity has property $P$. (This verifies that $H$ is
>      nonempty.)
> 3. Assume that two elements $a$ and $b$ have property $P$.
> 4. Use the assumption that $a$ and $b$ have property $P$ to show that $ab^{-1}$ has pro­perty $P$.

They follow with an example:

> Let $G$ be an Abelian group with identity $e$. Then show $H = (x \in G | x^2 = e)$ is a subgroup of $G$.

They write:

> Here, the defining property of $H$ is the condition $x^2=e$. So, we first note that $e^2 = e$, so that H is nonempty. Now we assume that $a$ and $b$ belong to $H$. This means that $a^2$=e and $b^2 = e$. Finally, we must show that $(ab^{-1}) = e$. (Computations follow)

In the foregoing example: I'm confused how we can jump from $H$ is non-empty to assuming there are elements $a$ and $b$ that are available to work with. Doesn't non-empty mean there's only *one* element we can assume that exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They indeed conclude that $H$ is not empty. However that conclusion on its own has no connection with the next step. There they **assume** that $a,b\in H$ and such assumption can be made also if you don't know  whether $H$ is empty or not. A bit confusing is that they say "**Now** we assume..." The word "now" can make you think that there is a connection, but there is not.

The verification rules can be checked in arbitrary order.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but they say the last three steps are "similar" to the second principle of induction where one: 1. shows that one number has a property (say $a$), 2. Assume true for $a \leq k < n$, 3. Show that this implies the property of number $n$. In this case 2. follows from 1. Should it not be true in my question as well?

Comment: They literally use "similar" so it could be I over-interpreted the strength of correspondence.

Comment: Also by a proof by induction you can start with proving $P(n+1)$ on base of $P(n)$ and after that prove the base case. Essential is only that both things are done. Further they have no connection.

Answer (score 3):

If $H$ has only one element, then you only have to check $P$ for $a=b$. (Nowhere does it say that $a$ and $b$ must be distinct)

Comment: hi, I think I didn't quite make my question clear. Included the specific example that I was confused about.

Comment: I think the answer still applies. You're asked to show that for all $a$ and $b$ in $H$ such that $P(a)$ and $P(b)$ are true, then $P(ab^{-1})$ is true. Well just because $H$ only has one element $e$ doesn't mean you can't still test the validity of the statement "If $P(e)$ is true and $P(e)$ is true, then $P(ee^{-1})$ is true".

Comment: If $H=\varnothing$ then the statement is vacuously true, so then you don't even need a test.

Comment: Exactly drhab. But OP was asking about the general kind of situation, more than this specific question.